# Set size of UIImageView

Tags: swift, image, uiimage

I have a very simple question,
I am working in the storyboard and is dragging a uiimageview into the viewcontroller. I configure the imageview to be square (like 100*100). I now set the image to something that has another aspect ratio (like 100*150). When I build the app I expect the imageView to be square (100*100) as i have set in the constraints, but instead it shows the imageView with the image size. So in other words, what I am asking is: How can I set the imageView to the exact size I want so it overwrites the image size? Hope this makes sense, else I can try to explain it a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set `imageView.clipsToBounds = true` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick:) Cant I set this in the identity inspector?

Comment: If I'm correct, `Clip Subviews` in `Attributes inspector` should be the one you need